# Material Design Lite - JS Not applying event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

I'm having a strange problem with Material Design Lite library. I've included the mdl js script tag before closing the `body` tag, according to documentation.
However, I'm unable to apply the styling from the mdl library. Upon inspecting the dev tools, I found that the event listeners from `material.min.js` aren't being applied to the text fields and buttons, etc. I'm attaching two images to better explain the situation.

[image: MDL files are being loaded correctly.]

As you can see, the files are being loaded...

[image: Styling not working as intended]

But I can't see any animations from the MDL for text fields.

PS. I'm running the website on a local server.
Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <!-- google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- icons -->
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/fonts/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <!--bootstrap -->
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Material Design Lite CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/portal/assets/plugins/material/material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/portal/assets/css/material_style.css">
    <!-- Theme Styles -->
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/css/theme/light/theme_style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="rt_style_components" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/css/theme/light/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/css/plugins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/static/portal/assets/css/theme/light/theme-color.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="page-header-fixed sidemenu-closed-hidelogo page-content-white page-md">
...
<!-- start js include path -->
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/popper/popper.js" ></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockui.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<!-- Common js-->
<script src="/static/portal/assets/js/app.js" ></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/js/layout.js" ></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/js/theme-color.js" ></script>
<!-- Material -->
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/material/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/js/pages/material-select/getmdl-select.js" ></script>
<script  src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/material-datetimepicker/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script  src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/material-datetimepicker/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script  src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/material-datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js"></script>
<!-- dropzone -->
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.js" ></script>
<script src="/static/portal/assets/plugins/dropzone/dropzone-call.js" ></script>
<!-- end js include path -->


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added please take a look...

Comment: It is likely a conflict between MDL and one or more of the other libraries you are using (bootstrap would be my first guess). If you are just using MDL for a particular component, then you are better off looking into [Material Components for the web](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web) where you can just include the code for individual components reducing the potential conflict issues. You could also look into one of the bootstrap-specific material libraries as well.

Comment: I'm using a theme so I'm stuck with MDL. I removed all script tags except for MDL one and still no luck...

Comment: Posted a working minimal MDL setup in an answer (too much for a comment) that will hopefully help you as a starting point to test which libraries are conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic working example of an MDL button that may help as a reference in your troubleshooting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Material Design Lite Button example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Accent-colored raised button with ripple -->
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
    Button
  </button>

  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was copy-pasting the **rendered** widget from my template, which had already added `data-upgraded` attribute. Just follow MDL documentation and you should be fine.